SSD reallocated sector count
It seems like all critical attributes (Reallocated sector count, Reported uncorrectable error, Reallocation event count) have some very big values but my health still says 100%.


Just to confirm, here's a report from program called Specify:

Right now, my drive is very fast, but just a few days ago it was very very slow constantly doing something in the background, boot and shutdown times were over 5 minutes! Is my drive still fine or it needs to go through a software for managing bad sectors or needs a complete replacement?

It's a SU630, just assume it needs replacement a month after opening the package.

@grawity_u1686 dawg it served me perfectly for almost 5 years, please refrain from useless commenting. I just observed that 12B = 300 reallocation events is a bit too high especially for a crappy SSD and still I didn't get any warnings or health issues in the crystal disk program. 300 uncorrectable errors is also a whole lot so I am suspecting of a software bug.

@DaniloJonić - Honest feedback isn’t always useless. I was going to help you but if your going to react that way to another user, I am going to choose to help someone else, Crystal Disk is software it can also have errors I have a theory of what’s going on but can’t confirm with the information provided

We replaced around ~100 HDDs with ADATA SSDs at work – regular Windows PCs that run Word and Firefox at most. Two years later, I had a 15-stack of dead SU630s and SU650s on my desk (at least four had the issue of "every other megabyte being read at kB/s speeds"), with wildly different looking SMART reports depending on which batch they came from – it's almost like they have five different products with entirely different internals all named "SU650 240GB", and it practically boils down to whether you're lucky to get the better ones.
